# Listwise "summation", replacing empty lists with non-empty ones and ignoring "sum" of non-empty lists

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, code-review

Given two lists of equal length, `l1` and `l2`, both consisting of sublists that are either empty or non-empty - but corresponding sublists are never non-empty - the task is to consolidate or "collapse" the lists to make a new list `newList` where

- if the `n`th element of `l1` is an empty list, but the same element of `l2` is not, then `newList[[n]]` takes that sublist from `l2`;
- if the `n`th element of `l1` is non-empty, but the same element of `l2` is an empty list, then `newList[[n]]` takes that sublist from `l1`;
- if the `n`th element of both `l1` and `l2` are empty lists, then so will be the same element of `newList`

I have some working code for such a function, but I'm curious if there is a simpler or faster way to execute this sort of task. Perhaps I've overlooked a built-in method? Any suggestions appreciated (even for making the question title more concise).

```
Collapse[l1_List, l2_List] := Module[

    {newList, n, commonLength},

    newList = {};

    If[
        Length[l1] === Length[l2],

        commonLength = Length[l1]; n = 1;
        While[
            n <= commonLength,
            If[
                (l1[[n]] === {}) && (l2[[n]] =!= {}),
                AppendTo[newList, l2[[n]]],

                    If[
                        (l1[[n]] =!= {}) && (l2[[n]] === {}),
                        AppendTo[newList, l1[[n]]],

                        If[
                            (l1[[n]] =!= {}) && (l2[[n]] =!= {}),
                            Print["Lists are not collapsible"],
                            AppendTo[newList, {}]
                        ];

                    ];

                ];

            n++

        ];,

        Print["Lists are incompatible"];

    ];

    If[
        newList =!= {},
        Return[newList]
    ];

];
```

*Test cases*

```
Collapse[{{}}, {{}}]
(* {{}} *)

Collapse[{{}}, {{1}}]
(* {{1}} *)

Collapse[{{}, {1}, {}}, {{}, {}, {a}}]
(* {{}, {1}, {a}} *)

Collapse[{{}}, {{}, {}}]
(* Lists are incompatible *)

Collapse[{{1}}, {{a}}]
(* Lists are not collapsible *)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html) to generalize `If` statements, along with [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) and [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) to get:

```
collapse[l1_, l2_] := Which[
  Length[l1] != Length[l2],
  Print["Lists are incompatible"],
  Max[Min /@ Map[Length, Transpose[{l1, l2}], {2}]] != 0,
  Print["Lists are not collapsible"],
  True,
  MapThread[Join, {l1, l2}]]
```

Test lists all work as desired.

Answer (score 6):

I would create a helper function:

```
join[{}, a_] := a
join[a_, {}] := a
join[a_, b_] := (Print["Lists are not collapsible"]; $Failed)

collapse[a_, b_] := Quiet @ Check[
    MapThread[join, {a, b}],
    Print["Lists are incompatible"],
    MapThread::mptc
]
```

It's not exactly what your function returns, but it shouldn't be difficult to modify.